# How to place a image over eye and mouth using CIFeatures

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-image

I found this [link](http://www.icapps.be/face-detection-with-core-image-on-live-video/) to place the image over the face points. Like the same way I need to detect the eyes and place an image over there?

To be simple I need to place an image over the human eye. How can I do it? Any tips would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( CIFaceFeature *ff in features ) {

    // find the correct position for the square layer within the previewLayer

    // the feature box originates in the bottom left of the video frame.

    // (Bottom right if mirroring is turned on)

    CGRect faceRect = [ff bounds];



    // flip preview width and height

    CGFloat temp = faceRect.size.width;

    faceRect.size.width = faceRect.size.height;

    faceRect.size.height = temp;

    temp = faceRect.origin.x;

    faceRect.origin.x = faceRect.origin.y;

    faceRect.origin.y = temp;

    // scale coordinates so they fit in the preview box, which may be scaled

    CGFloat widthScaleBy = previewBox.size.width / clap.size.height;

    CGFloat heightScaleBy = previewBox.size.height / clap.size.width;

    faceRect.size.width *= widthScaleBy;

    faceRect.size.height *= heightScaleBy;

    faceRect.origin.x *= widthScaleBy;

    faceRect.origin.y *= heightScaleBy;



    if ( isMirrored )

        faceRect = CGRectOffset(faceRect, previewBox.origin.x + previewBox.size.width - faceRect.size.width - (faceRect.origin.x * 2), previewBox.origin.y);

    else

        faceRect = CGRectOffset(faceRect, previewBox.origin.x, previewBox.origin.y);
```

you can get the face rect but the u need to fine the eye of the image

this will help u to get the each position

```
-(void)markFaces:(CIImage *)image
{
    // draw a CI image with the previously loaded face detection picture
    @autoreleasepool {
        CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                                  context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracy forKey:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]];

        // create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector
        NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

        NSLog(@"The Address Of CIImage In: %p %s",image,__FUNCTION__);
        NSLog(@"Array Count %d",[features count]);


        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


        if([features count]==0)
        {
           //No image is present
        }
        else 
        {
            for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
            {

                if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
                {
                   // Your code based on the mouth position
                }


              if (faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition) {
                 // Write your code Note: points are mirrored point so u need to take care of that 

                }
                if (faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition) {
                 // Write your code Note: points are mirrored point so u need to take care of that 

                }

                }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will give a try and let you know!

Comment: I have done detecting eyes. But my problem is to make a overlay image over the eyes? How to make it? i.e Instaed of circles or squares I need a overlay image over the eyes.

Comment: @3DNewbie did you find the way to do ? i'm also stuck in the same

Comment: @3DNewbie How to set the mirrored EyePosition? I'm trying to apply overlay image on runtime front camera.

Answer (score 0):

Apple iOS 5 and later, has provided this functionality internally.

Refer this Apple Documentation regarding the same:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html

In this example, they are doing the same, as you required - Face and Eyes detection.

Hope this would be helpful for you.

*Also check these [link1](http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/22/ios-5-face-detection-with-core-image/) and [link2](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/) , it contains image overlay for the detected areas. I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thnaks for your reply. My intension is to place a overlay image on the eye position. How to do it? i.e Instaed of circles or squares I need a overlay image over the eyes.

Comment: In the other two links, you can find the same, where they are placing images only.

Comment: No the other two links draws the circle on the image and not placing the circle images over the eyes! Can you please guide me!

Comment: Sorry for incovience, check this link: http://www.icapps.com/face-detection-with-core-image-on-live-video/
Here image addition is there over face detection.